# Flutter: How to share image to whatsapp with high resolution

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-layout, whatsapp, flutter-dependencies

i'm currently trying to send an image, that contains widgets i screenshotd using the screenshot package.
and to share the image, i use 2 packages:
1st: saves image in galery (**image_gallery_saver**)
2nd: share the image - (**esys_flutter_share**)

but when i try to share into whatsapp, the resolution gets so bad.. can someone help im new.

Comment: Could you share some more info about the problem? I think that some code snippets may be helpful. Without that is might be pretty hard to suggest something constructive

Comment: i have already found it, thanks man.. but even tho i still cant share an image to whatsapp from flutter app with the same quality, whatsapp always reduce quality. I have tested with GBwhatsapp and it works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

you can using this
Share.shareFiles([ImagePath])

this using

import `'package:share/share.dart';`